# Responsive variants of display stopped working

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css

In my project I've made use of the responsive variants quite a lot. As an example I some times need to hide something on mobile displays and use the classes `hidden sm:flex` or `hidden md:block` etc. This has worked perfectly for quite some time, but suddenly some of the classes stopped working without any obvious reason. In some parts of the page they work, and some parts they don't.

I've disabled purging, JIT, re-installed tailwind, compiled on different computers and everything else I can think of. None of it has made any change to this issue.

Note, I've fixed the duplication issue and this was not related to the problem.

From the picture below you can see that the class is set on the DOM element, but it does not register on the applied CSS styles.

[image: Demonstration of the problem]

tailwind.config.js

```js
module.exports = {
  purge: {
    enabled: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    content: [
      'components/**/*.{vue,js}',
      'layouts/**/*.vue',
      'pages/**/*.vue',
      'plugins/**/*.{js,ts}',
      'nuxt.config.{js,ts}',
    ],
    safelist: [],
  },
  future: {
    removeDeprecatedGapUtilities: true,
    purgeLayersByDefault: true,
  },
  prefix: '',
  important: false,
  separator: ':',
  theme: {
    extend: {
      transitionProperty: {
        'max-height': 'max-height',
      },
      colors: {
        'al-green-light': '#7e997a',
        'al-green': '#6C8469',
        'al-green-medium': '#566954',
        'al-green-dark': '#111411',
        'al-red': '#cf4040',
        'al-yellow': '#FFBF00',
        'al-beige': '#fbf8f5',
        'al-gray': '#767676',
      },
      zIndex: {
        '-1': '-1',
        'card-backdrop': '100',
        'card-logo': '110',
        'card-content': '120',
        dropdown: '500',
        navigation: '900',
        modal: '1000',
        'modal-backdrop': '1010',
        'modal-content': '1020',
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    backgroundColor: ['disabled', 'hover'],
    padding: ['group-hover'],
    display: ['group-hover'],
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

tailwind.css

```css
/* purgecss start ignore */
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
/* purgecss end ignore */
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

nuxt.config.js

```js
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss', 
  ],
  tailwindcss: {
    exposeConfig: true,
  },
```

Comment: Did you edit the `tailwind.config.js` file with some custom breakpoints here?

Comment: No, I haven't changed the breakpoints in any way.

Comment: Where does the 2nd CSS class comes from? You should have it's name on the right in your devtools.

Comment: The duplicate CSS comes from the same file, so apparently it's added twice somewhere. But I cannot seem to find out where.

Comment: Ok, I fixed the duplication issue. The CSS was included twice due to some line another developer added ages ago. The main issue still remains the same though.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by adding

```js
  variants: {
    display: ['responsive'],
  },
```

to my tailwind.config.js

However, this should not be necessary since by default responsive variants should be generated for display utilities according to the Tailwind Docs.